# Show most recent post - if "yes" chosen as radio button value

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Here is the setup for my radio button:
[image]

I can't seem to get the posts that are valued at yes to display in the loop..

Here is my loop:

```
<?php
$args = array( 
   'numberposts'   => 1,
   'post_type'     => 'event',
   'posts_per_page' => '1',
   'meta_key'      => 'sponsored_event',
   'meta_value'    => 'yes'
   );
   $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>    
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>        
<div class="sponsored-event">
<div class="sponsored-image" style="background-image: url(<?php the_field( 'event_image' ); ?>);"></div>
<div class="sponsored-info">
     <h2>Sponsored Event</h2>
     <h1><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></h1>
         <p><strong>Date</strong></p><br>
         <p class="place"><?php the_field( 'event_location' ); ?></p>
         <p class="time"><?php the_field( 'event_time' ); ?></p>
         <p><?php the_field( 'excerpt' ); ?></p>
         </div>
         </div>        
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'showposts' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'meta_query' => array(
            array(
            'key' => 'sponsored_event',
            'value' => 1,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>


            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><div class="sponsored-event">
                <div class="sponsored-image" style="background-image: url(<?php the_field( 'event_image' ); ?>);">
                </div>
                <div class="sponsored-info">
                    <h2>Sponsored Event</h2>
                    <h1><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong></h1>
                    <p><strong>Date</strong></p><br>
                    <p class="place"><?php the_field( 'event_location' ); ?></p>
                    <p class="time"><?php the_field( 'event_time' ); ?></p>
                    <p><?php the_field( 'excerpt' ); ?></p>
                </div>
            </div></a>


    <?php endwhile; else: ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `meta_query` to accomplish this. Update your `$args` with something like the following:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
          'key'     => 'sponsored_event',
          'compare' => 'LIKE',
          'value'   => 'yes',
      ),
    ),
);
```

You also need to update `if ( have_posts() )` to `if ( $the_query->have_posts() )`.

More information about `meta_query` can be found here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: I have tried numerous changes in my meta_query and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: You also have an issue with your if statement. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using both post_per_page and number posts you can use any one of your choice

Try any of the Methods as available below. As per the `ACF` the `Method 1` is suggested but as for as the WordPress you can retrieve information based on `Method 2` also.

**Method:1**

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page'  => 1,
  'post_type'       => 'event',
  'meta_key'        => 'sponsored_event',
  'meta_value'  => 'yes'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
<?php if ($the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
//Your Code over here to Manipulate
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Method:2**

Try the meta query with compare as `=` operator in the `meta_query`.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
          'key'     => 'sponsored_event',
          'compare' => '=',
          'value'   => 'yes',
      ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Hi Naresh, I've previously given [some feedback on using yellow quote blocks as general headings or as a highligher box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255026/show-post-if-true-false-is-yes-advanced-custom-fields/39255165#comment65846710_39255165). Was anything unclear about my remark?

Comment: @halfer. Sorriee bro. hereafter i will not use that for general headings.Can you pls suggest me where to use these yellow highlighter boxes in my replies.

Answer (score 0):

`if ( have_posts() )` should reference the query: `if ( $the_query->have_posts() )`.

Also, as has already been mentioned, you should use `'posts_per_page' => 1,` instead of `numberposts`.

Comment: This still doesn't output any posts.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code on my machine and it works fine! Just (as already mentioned from others) the `if()` statement is wrong, change it to:

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() )
```

But now I have a really silly question... After creating the ACF field, have you saved some posts (events) with the meta field (yes or no) ? If not, WP wont find anything because the postmeta is not saved into the DB.

Did you took a look into the DB if the postmeta is saved correctly?